# Laravel - order collection by relatioship

Tags: php, laravel, sql-order-by, relationship

I have collection that I need to order like this:

- So if my Model has that relationship it needs to be first on a list
- If my Model does not have that relationship it needs to list after the Model that has relatioship

Here is my relationship function:

```
public function adMegaPremiumAdObjects()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(MegaPremiumAdObject::class, 'ad_id', 'id');
    }
```

And with this I can only order my collection with fields inside that table:

```
public function index()
    {
        $collection = AdObject::orderBy('some_field', 'DESC')->get();
    }
```

So I need to order this collection by my relationship `adMegaPremiumAdObjects` - if some Model have that relationship it needs to show first in a list.

If I try with `whereHas` it only shows me collection with that relationship and that doesn't help me.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `withCount()` to add a relation count column, which you can order by:

```
$collection = AdObject::withCount('adMegaPremiumAdObjects')->orderBy('adMegaPremiumAdObjects_count', 'DESC')->get();
```

From Laravel docs:

> If you want to count the number of results from a relationship without
> actually loading them you may use the **withCount** method, which will
> place a {relation}_count column on your resulting models.

Comment: Okay, so I tried it but it shows me error:
```SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'adMegaPremiumAdObjects_count' in 'order clause'```

Comment: I'm using Laravel 7 version

Comment: And I did ```'strict' => false``` for mysql database

Comment: When you log the query by replacing `get()` with `toSql()`, what does it show? e.g. `dd(AdObject::withCount...etc...->toSql());`

Comment: I am testing this in Laravel 5.8, but I see no reason it should not work in 7.

Comment: I done this doing: ```->with('adPremiumAdObjects')->sortByDesc(function($query){ return $query->adMegaPremiumAdObects->count() });```